# UWP TreeView sort leads to random events

Tags: c#, uwp, treeview, uwp-xaml

Team,
I run in a very weird issue with treeview.
Here are the steps to rep:
1. create a new project
2. select Window Studio Template 
3. Select MVVM Light 
4. Add treeview page 
5. create project 
6. Open TreeViewPage.xaml and add with:

```
    xmlns:Custom="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    xmlns:helper="using:TitoDoc2020.Helpers"
    <Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RadioButtonRevealStyle" TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPadding}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Grid
    x:Name="RootGrid"
    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
    CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">
    <ContentPresenter
    x:Name="ContentPresenter"
    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
    VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
    AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
    ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
    CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" />

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">

    <Storyboard>
    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
    </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>

    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
    <VisualState.Setters>
    <Setter Target="RootGrid.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBackgroundPointerOver}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
    </VisualState.Setters>

    <Storyboard>
    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
    </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>

    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
    <VisualState.Setters>
    <Setter Target="RootGrid.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBackgroundPressed}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBorderBrushPressed}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundPressed}" />
    </VisualState.Setters>

    <Storyboard>
    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
    </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>

    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
    <VisualState.Setters>
    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBackgroundDisabled}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBorderBrushDisabled}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
    </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>

    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
    <VisualState.Setters>
    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBackgroundChecked}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBorderBrushChecked}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundChecked}" />
    </VisualState.Setters>

    <Storyboard>
    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
    </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver">
    <VisualState.Setters>
    <Setter Target="RootGrid.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBackgroundCheckedPointerOver}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBorderBrushCheckedPointerOver}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundCheckedPointerOver}" />
    </VisualState.Setters>

    <Storyboard>
    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
    </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPressed">
    <VisualState.Setters>
    <Setter Target="RootGrid.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBackgroundCheckedPressed}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBorderBrushCheckedPressed}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundCheckedPressed}" />
    </VisualState.Setters>

    <Storyboard>
    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
    </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="CheckedDisabled">
    <VisualState.Setters>
    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBackgroundCheckedDisabled}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBorderBrushCheckedDisabled}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundCheckedDisabled}" />
    </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
    <VisualState.Setters>
    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBackgroundIndeterminate}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBorderBrushIndeterminate}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundIndeterminate}" />
    </VisualState.Setters>

    <Storyboard>
    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
    </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePointerOver">
    <VisualState.Setters>
    <Setter Target="RootGrid.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBackgroundIndeterminatePointerOver}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBorderBrushIndeterminatePointerOver}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundIndeterminatePointerOver}" />
    </VisualState.Setters>

    <Storyboard>
    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
    </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePressed">
    <VisualState.Setters>
    <Setter Target="RootGrid.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBackgroundIndeterminatePressed}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBorderBrushIndeterminatePressed}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundIndeterminatePressed}" />
    </VisualState.Setters>

    <Storyboard>
    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
    </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminateDisabled">
    <VisualState.Setters>
    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBackgroundIndeterminateDisabled}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonRevealBorderBrushIndeterminateDisabled}" />
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundIndeterminateDisabled}" />
    </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>

    </VisualStateGroup>

    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>

    </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="treeViewColumn" MinWidth="150" MaxWidth="350" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualState>
    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
    <!--641 is the default CompactModeThresholdWidth in NavigationView -->
    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="641" />
    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
    <VisualState.Setters>
    <Setter Target="header.Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
    <Setter Target="treeViewColumn.Width" Value="350" />
    <Setter Target="treeViewColumn.MaxWidth" Value="500" />
    </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid
    Background="{ThemeResource  SystemChromeMediumLowColor}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid
    Margin="80,0,0,0"
    x:Name="header"
    Grid.Row="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock
    x:Uid="TreeViewTitle"
    Margin="{StaticResource SmallLeftMargin}"
    Style="{StaticResource ListTitleStyle}"
    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <Button
    Grid.Column="1"
    x:Uid="TreeView_CollapseAllButton"
    Content="&#xF165;"
    FontSize="14"
    Padding="{StaticResource SmallLeftRightMargin}"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
    Command="{Binding ElementName=collapseBehavior, Path=CollapseAllCommand}"
    Background="Transparent" />
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel
    Grid.Row="1"
    x:DefaultBindMode="OneWay"
    Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Custom:RadioButtons MaxColumns="2">
    <RadioButton
    x:Name="SortDate"
    Width="50"
    Height="50"
    MinWidth="50"
    Margin="{StaticResource ButtonPadding}"
    Background="Transparent"
    Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.RadioButton_ClickAsync}"
    CornerRadius="2,2,2,2"
    Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonRevealStyle}"
    Checked="{x:Bind ViewModel.RadioButton_Checked}">
    <RadioButton.Content>
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <FontIcon
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.RowSpan="2"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
    FontSize="32"
    Glyph="&#xEC92;" />
    <FontIcon
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="1"
    FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
    Foreground="Transparent"
    Glyph="&#xEC92;" />
    <FontIcon
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="1"
    FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
    Foreground="Transparent"
    Glyph="&#xEC92;" />
    <FontIcon
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="1"
    FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
    Foreground="Transparent"
    Glyph="&#xEC92;" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
    <FontIcon
    Margin="0,6,0,0"
    FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
    FontSize="12"
    Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColorDark2}"
    Glyph="{x:Bind ViewModel.ImageSrcD}" />
    </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    </RadioButton.Content>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton
    x:Name="SortAlph"
    Width="50"
    Height="50"
    MinWidth="50"
    Margin="{StaticResource ButtonPadding}"
    Background="Transparent"
    Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.RadioButton_ClickAsync}"
    CornerRadius="2,2,2,2"
    Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonRevealStyle}"
    Checked="{x:Bind ViewModel.RadioButton_Checked}">
    <RadioButton.Content>
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <FontIcon
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.RowSpan="2"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
    FontSize="32"
    Glyph="&#xEA4A;" />
    <FontIcon
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Height="20"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
    Foreground="Transparent"
    Glyph="&#xEC92;" />
    <FontIcon
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="1"
    FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
    Foreground="Transparent"
    Glyph="&#xEC92;" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
    <FontIcon
    Margin="0,6,0,0"
    FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
    FontSize="12"
    Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColorDark2}"
    Glyph="{x:Bind ViewModel.ImageSrcA}" />
    </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    </RadioButton.Content>
    </RadioButton>
    </Custom:RadioButtons>
    </StackPanel>

    <winui:TreeView
    x:Name="treeView"
    Grid.Row="2"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.SampleItems}"
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TreeViewTemplateSelector}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <behaviors:TreeViewCollapseBehavior x:Name="collapseBehavior" />
    <ic:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemInvoked">
    <ic:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.ItemInvokedCommand}" />
    </ic:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </winui:TreeView>
    </Grid>
    </Grid>
    </Page>
```

7. Open TreeViewModel.cs and add replace with:

```
    public string _sorting;
    public bool _DateAsc;
    public bool _AlphAsc;
    public bool _SwapCheck = false;
    public bool _filterData = false;
    public int _filterDataSpan = 0;

    public string ImageSrcD
    {
    get
    {
    if (_DateAsc)
    {
    return "\xF0AD";
    }//SvgImageSource svgImage = new SvgImageSource(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Image_16x.png"));
    else
    {
    return "\xF0AE";
    }
    }
     set { Set<bool>(ref _DateAsc, bool.Parse(value)); }
    }

    public string ImageSrcA
    {
    get
    {
    if (_AlphAsc)
    {
    return "\xF0AD";
    }//SvgImageSource svgImage = new SvgImageSource(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Image_16x.png"));
    else
    {
    return "\xF0AE";
    }
    }
     set { Set<bool>(ref _AlphAsc, bool.Parse(value)); }
    }


    public async Task LoadDataAsync()
    {
    var data = await SampleDataService.GetTreeViewDataAsync();
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
    SampleItems.Add(item);
    }
    }

    public async Task SortDataAsync()
    {
    var data = await SampleDataService.GetTreeViewDataAsync();
    switch (_sorting)
    {
    default:
    break;
    case "SortAlph":
    if (_AlphAsc)
    {
    data = data
    .OrderBy(b => b.Country).ThenBy(b => b.CompanyName)
    .ToList();
    }
    else
    {
    data = data
    .OrderByDescending(b => b.Country).ThenByDescending(b => b.CompanyName)
    .ToList();
    }
    break;
    }
    SelectedItem = null;
    SampleItems.Clear();

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
    SampleItems.Add(item);
    }
    }

    public async void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    _SwapCheck = true;
    /*string sorting = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.ReadAsync<string>("TreeViewSort");

    switch (((RadioButton)sender).Name)
    {
    case "SortDate":
    if (sorting == "SortDate")
    {
    return;
    }
    SortAlph.IsChecked = false;
    break;
    case "SortAlph":
    if (sorting == "SortAlph")
    {
    return;
    }
    SortDate.IsChecked = false;
    break;
    default:
    break;
    }
     ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.SaveAsync("TreeViewSort", ((ToggleButton)sender).Name);
    _sorting = ((RadioButton)sender).Name;
    SortTreeAsync();
    //await LoadTreeAsync();
    */
    }

    public void RadioButton_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    switch (((RadioButton)sender).Name)
    {
    case "SortAlph":
    if (!_SwapCheck)
    {
    ImageSrcA = (!_AlphAsc).ToString();
    }
    break;
    case "SortDate":
    if (!_SwapCheck)
    {
    ImageSrcD = (!_DateAsc).ToString();
    }
    break;
    default:
    break;
    }
    _SwapCheck = false;
    _sorting = ((RadioButton)sender).Name;
    SortDataAsync();
    //SortTreeAsync();
    }
    }
    }
```

8. under Helpers folder create a class named TitoDoc2020Enums.cs paste:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace TitoDoc2020.Helpers
    {
    public enum LoadingStatus 
    {
    NotStarted = 0,
    Loading = 1,
    Loaded = 2
    }
    public enum VisualizationFormat 
    {
    // Surname, Name
    SurCName= 0,
    // Surname Name
    SurnName = 1,
    // Name Surname
    NameSur = 2
    }
    public enum Sorting
    {
    // Surname, Name
    Surname = 0,
    // Surname Name
    Name = 1
    }

    public enum DateFilter
    {
    Day =  1, // 59583, // &#xE8BF;
    Week = 2, // 59584, // &#xE8C0;
    Month = 3, // 59271, // &#xE787;
    Year = 4, // // &#xE1DB;
    All = 0 //60041 // &#xEA89
    }
    }
```

9. Update all NuGet libraries and add compile
10. Click the right sorting icon multiple times, you can open some tree view items, everything happens... items get opened automatically, I even got the request to use the microphone

It does not seem to me I'm doing anything strange... why is so messed up?

Comment: Here you have the complete project and a video of what happens: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AohVtHaw3aCiwrw81EYHqNY-9Xtqfg?e=4AOIaN

Answer (score 0):

nice to see you again, I could run this code sample and reproduce your problem easily. The problem is that you have not specific  bool `IsExpanded` property for the model and bind it to `TreeViewItem`  IsExpanded property. When you reorder the data current UI state will be covered by previous.

Please add the following to your model class and bind `IsExpanded` in xaml code.

```
public class SampleCompany : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    private bool isExpanded;
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            if (isExpanded != value)
            {
                isExpanded = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
            }
        }
    }

}

public class SampleOrder : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    private bool isExpanded;
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            if (isExpanded != value)
            {
                isExpanded = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Xaml code**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CompanyTemplate" x:DataType="model:SampleCompany">
    <winui:TreeViewItem
        AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind CompanyName}"
        IsExpanded="{x:Bind IsExpanded, Mode=OneWay}"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Orders}">
        <TextBlock Margin="{StaticResource XXSmallTopRightBottomMargin}" Text="{x:Bind CompanyName}" />
    </winui:TreeViewItem>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="OrderTemplate" x:DataType="model:SampleOrder">
    <winui:TreeViewItem
        AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind OrderID}"
        IsExpanded="{x:Bind IsExpanded, Mode=OneWay}"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Details}">
        <TextBlock Margin="{StaticResource XXSmallTopRightBottomMargin}" Text="{x:Bind ShortDescription}" />
    </winui:TreeViewItem>
</DataTemplate>
```

**Update**

> I've added the code but the Set part is never used and the Get part is read only when the parent is accessed

It's by-design, because, we use `OneWay` model, it will not edit the model property when you expand the tree view node. If we set it as TwoWay model set method will called.

> BUT now the issue is that when I re-create the object I loose the status so they are all closed again.

When we re-create object but not specific IsExpanded value (default value is false),so all the nodes will close by default.

Comment: I've added the code but the Set part is never used and the Get part is read only when the parent is accessed. Let me be more clear: I run the example, I Expand Company A -> Sample Order IsExpanded is read 3 times. The number of orders I have under company A. But if I expand an order the IsExpanded Set is NOT called. Nor it is read again. I changed it in TwoWay so it is saved. BUT now the issue is that when I re-create the object I loose the status so they are all closed again.

Comment: Please check in the Folder v2. It does save the status as you suggest but when I click and select items I get a crash (not even and exception). I've added even a video. I'm very confused on why TreeView is so unstable. (Note it happens even with your code)

Comment: I've enabled all the Common Language Runtime Exception and I get: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'TestSort.ViewModels.ShellViewModel' to type 'TestSort.Core.Models.SampleCompany'.'
and then when I select an item it crashes

Comment: Thank you Nico, but in any case the App crashes. Can you check my project and the video?

Comment: Yep, I could reproduce that, that's very interesting, I need do more testing to confirm this.

Comment: Nico :) happy to help... and very sorry to be such a good "bug hunter"!

Comment: Any update on this? where you able to find a solution? I'm blocked in the development from all the issues on TreeView and thinking to swap to WPF but I would really like to do UWP